# Gnu Make: When invoking parallel make, if pre-requisites are supplied during the build, will make try to remake those?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is an order of operations question.

Suppose I declare a list of requirements:

```
required:=$(patsubst %.foo,%.bar, $(shell find * -name '.foo'))
```

And a rule to make those requirements:

```
$(required):
   ./foo.py $@
```

Finally, I invoke the work with:

```
make foo -j 10
```

Suppose further the job is taking days and days (up to a week on this slow desktop computer).

In order to speed things up, I'd like to generate a list of commands and do some of the work on the **Much** faster laptop.  I can't do all of the work on the laptop because, for whatever reason, it can't stay up for hours and hours without discharging and suspending (if I had to guess, probably due to thermal throttling):

```
make -n foo > outstanding_jobs

cat outstanding_jobs | sort -r | sponge outstanding_jobs
scp slow_box:outstanding_jobs fast_laptop:outstanding_jobs

ssh fast_laptop
head -n 200 outstanding_jobs | parallel -j 12
scp *.bar slow_box:.
```

The question is:

**If I put `*.bar` in the directory where the original make job was run**, will make still try to do that job on the slow box?

**OR** do I have to halt the job on the slow box and re-invoke make to "get credit" in the make recipe for the new work that I've synced over onto the slow box?

Comment: "(if I had to guess, probably due to thermal throttling)" FYI, try the `cpufrequtils` package. You can, among other things, set the maximum clock your CPU will *ever* use.

Comment: That said, for your main question, I've had makefiles where files were actually updated by a rule different than the one for that filename, and it seemed to work fairly well.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question.  Are you saying that the slow system and fast system are both running on some shared storage, say via NFS or something, so that they share the same source tree etc. but two different hosts are building on it?

Comment: @MadScientist they are running different operating systems (linux and MacOS).  I ran into issues setting up shared storage on the Mac side, so I abandoned that idea (time).  ATM I am duplicating the data and running batches of commands from the bottom (reverse sort) of the output from `make foo -n` locally without any `make` at all.  The plan is to sync the dirs with rsync.  And, so that I can automate this overnight, it's important to know whether make will re-run the completed files as they appear in batches, since each individual job is long running, and halting + re-invoking is costly.

Comment: @o11c thanks for that! the MBP seems to overclock into the battery, and can't pull enough power through the brick to stay up.  Everything is so thin and minimized, I just assume heat is an issue at the power ingress point (or just that the supply isn't there).

Comment: I guess you mean you're going to try to rsync the contents while make is running?  All I can say is that it sounds dangerous to me.  Make really expects to "own" all the files it's considering as targets.  It doesn't expect them to possibly change out from under it while it's working on them.

Comment: @MadScientist these files won't be used downstream -- they are the output exhaust  of a parser. As long as the parser runs for everything, all is well. I can de-duplicate parsed outputs (lines in files) afterwards...  from what it sounds like, I can point a bunch of machines at this dir via sshfs and (for the mac) rsync, and invoke make from each?  Make will run through the logic for whether a rule's operand needs generation at the time of execution, even in parallel mode?

Comment: @MadScientist on second thought, rsync scares me a bit, so I'll leave the mac out of it

Comment: @MadScientist but I got more resources so the `sshfs` sltn applies now

Comment: The basis of my comment is that you can't have two make instances running the same makefile in the same directory at the same time, reliably.  Whether they're running on the same system, or two different systems with a shared filesystem, or even two different systems with an rsync copy between them.  The problem is both makefiles may check the same target at the same time, both see it needs to be updated, then both invoke commands to update it and these commands may interfere with each other and corrupt the output.  This is a classic race condition scenario.

Comment: @MadScientist ah, got it. so you don't think that the dumper/file writer that writes a single line of output to the respective file will necessarily lock the file for the entire duration of a write? Or the drive during the file creation process?  Because if the race conditions are violated from line-to-line, that is fine.  But in this case, if there are multiple writes from multiple files on the same atomic line write, then output could be corrupted for that line.  I know this is out of scope, but do you think that is a possibility?

Comment: It really depends on your environment.  However, unless you're using some specialized filesystem it's definitely _not_ the case that a file is locked to a single writer automatically.  It's possible that the dumper/file writer is locking the file but that is highly unusual: it requires extra work and so unless it's documented that way I would doubt it.  If all you care about is adding a short line then IF the file is opened in append mode it will PROBABLY be OK since small appends are "accidentally" atomic.  Really, it's just a risk and I wouldn't take it with my build system.  YMMV.

Comment: @MadScientist I wound up siloing the processes on the two linux boxes I have access to now, and using the Mac as C&C/sink.  The faster box is running a `make -j 46 foo`; the slower box is running a `make foo -n | sort -r | parallel` (so the job in reverse order), and I am collating on the mac.  I guess my next goal with Make is going to be proper C&C where I send out jobs to the remote boxes from the C&C... in the interest of avoiding writing code for automation, is this something that make is capable of intrinsically?

Comment: No, make has no built in support for remote job distribution.  However there are ways to integrate existing facilities to do this, you don't have to roll your own.  Unfortunately I can't remember any offhand--memory is especially bad today :(

Comment: @MadScientist no prob -- found out about SLURM.  Looks like you guys added SLURM integration to make back in 3.8.  Going to try that out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE: substantially revised.**

Before it starts building anything, `make` constructs a dependency graph to guide it, based on an analysis of the requested goal(s), the applicable build rules, and, to some extent, the files already present.  It then walks the graph, starting from the goal nodes, to determine which are out of date with respect to their prerequisites and update them.

Although it does not necessarily evaluate the whole graph before running any recipes, once it decides that a given target needs to be updated, `make` is committed to updating it.  In particular, once `make` decides that some direct or indirect prerequisite of `T` is out of date, it is committed to (re)building `T`, too, regardless of any subsequent action on `T` by another process.
So, ...

> **If I put `*.bar` in the directory where the original make job was run**,
> will make still try to do that job on the slow box?

Adding files to the build directory after `make` starts building things will not necessarily affect which targets the ongoing `make` run will attempt to build, nor which recipes it uses to build them.  The nearer a target is to a root of the dependency graph, the less likely that the approach described will affect whether `make` performs a rebuild, especially if you're running a parallel `make`.

It's possible that you would see some time savings, but you must also consider the possibility that you end up with an inconsistent build.

> **OR** do I have to halt the job on the slow box and re-invoke make to "get credit" in the make recipe for the new work that I've synced over onto the slow box?

If the possibility of an inconsistent build can be discounted, then that is probably a viable option.  A new `make` run will take the then-existing files into account.  Depending on the defined rules and the applicable timestamps, it is still possible that some targets would be rebuilt that did not really need to be, but unless the makefile engages in unusual shennanigans, chances are good that at least most of the built files imported from the helper machine will be accepted and used without rebuilding.

Comment: Just to say it's a little misleading to say that make chooses its build plan by analyzing the dependency graph before it starts building anything.  In fact, make doesn't actually plan out anything: it reads all the makefiles and constructs the dependency graph, yes, then it chooses the starting node on the graph and begins walking it, building nodes as it determines they are out of date.  It just keeps walking until suddenly it finds there's nothing left to do (all nodes from the starting node have been visited), then it stops.

Comment: However, you are correct that once the dependency graph is computed it won't be changed as make runs.  Of course, implicit rules don't quite obey that rule because they can cause extra build operations to be run that aren't specifically visible in the graph when it's constructed.

Comment: I have perhaps been over-general, @MadScientist, but do you agree that once `make` decides it to build some target, it does not re-evaluate that decision, even if, say, that target is created or updated by a different process while `make` is working on its prerequisites?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the key point is that make doesn't decide a priori whether or not to build all targets when the build is starting up.  That decision is a point-in-time decision taken with whatever info make has at the moment the decision is needed.  So if, for example, you have two different processes both modifying files, like two invocations of make or one make and one rsync or whatever, the results will be indeterminate (and indeterminte == "bad" when talking about builds :p )

Comment: @MadScientist, I have made a substantial revision.  I hope you find the resulting version more satisfactory.